# How to remove stop words from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I am working on a project which analyses Twitter data. I am in the pre-processing stage and am struggling to get my application to remove stop words from the dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')

self.file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop',
                                                        title='Select file',
                                                        filetypes=(('csv file', '*.csv'),
                                                                   ('csv file', '*.csv')))

for tw in df["txt"]:

            column_list = ["txt"]
            clean_tw = []
            df = pd.read_csv(self.file_name, usecols=column_list)
            stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

            tw = (re.sub("([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+(RT))", "", tw.lower()).split())
            if tw not in stop_words:
            filtered_tw = [w for w in tw if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
            clean_tw.append(filtered_tw)
```

I currently get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...", line 146, in clean_csv
    if tweet not in stop_words:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Your function has the variable “tweet” but I think that it should be labelled “tw” as in your for loop

Comment: @Matt I have changed it and the same error pops up.

Comment: Post complete error

Comment: Could you add sample of the text and also which library are you using to get the stopwords? At first glance I see:
- in line 3, there is a space in between `tw` and `.lower()`.
- in line 5, stopwords does not have the underscore as in the line above? I assume they are two different sets?

Doing it dummy way and setting `stop_words = ["an"]` it runs on my terminal...

Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @DeepakDixit I have added the full error output.

Comment: @ppanero I have added the libraries that I am using

Comment: @Rose, I have added an answer, spotted the problem :) hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to check if a list (the result from the regex) is in a set... this operation cannot be done. You need to loop through the list (or do some sort of set operation, e.g. `set(tw).difference(stop_words)`.

Just for clarity:

```py
>>> tw = (re.sub("([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+(RT))", "", initial.lower()).split())
>>> tw
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']
>>> set(tw).difference(stop_words)
{'example'}
```

Then just append to `clean_tw` the difference :) Something like:

```py
clean_tw = []
df = pd.read_csv(self.file_name, usecols=col_list)
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
tw = (re.sub("([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+(RT))", "", tw.lower()).split())
clean_tw.append(set(tw).difference(stop_words))
```

Lastly, you can define the `stop_words` outside the loop since it is going to be always the same set, so you improve a bit on performance :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI you should not be removing stopwords with regex when there are such great packages out there!

I recommend using `nltk` to tokenize and untokenize.

For each row in your csv:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

nltk.download('stopwords')

# get your stopwords from nltk
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# loop through your rows
for sent in sents:

    # tokenize
    tokenized_sent = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)

    # remove stops
    tokenized_sent_no_stops = [
        tok for tok in tokenized_sent 
        if tok not in stop_words
    ]

    # untokenize 
    untokenized_sent = TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize(
        tokenized_sent_no_stops
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it is probable that `tweet` is a list and `stop_words` is a set or dictionary.

```
>>> tweet = ['a','b']
>>> stop_words = set('abcdefg')
>>> tweet not in stop_words
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Try this instead

```
if not stop_words.intersection(tweet):
    ...
```

or

```
if stop_words.isdisjoint(tweet):
```